# Run python script from Task Manager using specific environment

Tags: python, batch-file, anaconda, taskmanager

I'm trying to run a python script through Task Manager from a specific virtual environment.

However, "activate.bat" only seems to exist in the root folder:

C:\Users\*user*\anaconda3\Scripts

but not in

C:\Users\*user*\anaconda3\envs\*env_name*\Scripts

I've tried using the following batch file as the Task Manager Program/Script but doesn't work (nothing happens).
Any ideas on how to call a specific env here? Thanks!

```
@echo off
cd C:\Users\*user*\Documents\folderName\Scripts
call C:\Users\*user*\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat env_name
python test.py
```

Comment: Another way (maybe easier) to specify the env you want is using os.environ - you can specify your environment in a file which you load within your script - the file could for example be parsed to the script using the argument parser

Comment: Try `path\to\venv\Scripts\python.exe test.py`

Comment: juhat, does simply pointing to the environment-specific python.exe actually mean that environment is called and all/only those packages are used?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, `conda run` should be preferred for *programmatic* execution within an environment. The `conda activate` command is intended for *interactive* use in a shell. That is, something like

```batch
@echo off
cd C:\Users\*user*\Documents\folderName\Scripts
conda run -n env_name python test.py
```

I'm not on Windows, but you may need `conda.exe` or a full path to the Conda executable instead of simply `conda`.